# Meteor bundle visualizer add dynamic imports to the initial client bundle

Tags: meteor, dynamic-import

I am currently using the Meteor `bundle-visualizer` package to check the initial package size.

I have already written my package in a way, that it uses `dynamic-import` and they work as expected in development mode.

However, when I run the `bundle-visualizer` via

```
meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer
```

I get the full package size to be displayed with all modules included. After a short research I found [this paragraph in the documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/bundle-visualizer.html):

> This visualization can uncover details about which files or packages are occupying space within the initial client bundle. This can be useful in determining which imports might be candidates for being converted to dynamic import() statements (which are excluded from the initial client bundle), or for identifying packages which have been inadvertently included in a project.

Where I am especially wondering about is the part

> (which are excluded from the initial client bundle)

,because this prevents me from getting the actual bundle size after converting it using dynamic imports. Thus I can't verify, if my package is below a certain KB in size.

Has anyone found a way to run `bundle-visualizer` with enabled `dynamic-import` for the initial client package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by accident I found the solution. Initially, I tried

```
meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer dynamic-import
```

or

```
meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer --extra-packages  dynamic-import
```

which **both have resulted in errors** and I thought, that this was just not possible.

However, if I add `dynamic-import` to the list of `--extra-packages` but without space and separated by a comma like

```
meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer,dynamic-import
```

it will run the `bundle-visualizer` with dynamic imports, revealing the "new" size after optimizations.